# Sass não reescreve arquivos com prefixo

Tags: sass

Eu copiei alguns arquivos .scss para o meu projeto, estes arquivos estão com prefixo _ no nome (ex. _style, _mediaqueries, etc.). O compass reescreve todos os arquivos normalmente, menos estes que estão com prefixos. Algumas pessoas me disseram que isso não deveria interferir no comportamento do Sass.

Alguém sabe me dizer se o problema está em alguma configuração, ou se ele realmente não lê arquivos com prefixos desse jeito?

Comment: Suponho que o seu problema seja o mesmo que o meu. Tenho trechos de código sendo importado no meu .scss principal e esses trechos de código não são reescritos quando mudados. Quando eu usava o ruby tudo funcionava normal, mudei para o node-sass e começou esse erro. Não sei porque, mas tirei os prefixos dos meus trechos e a coisa funcionou de novo.

Answer (score 0):

SASS interpreta os os arquivos começados com underline como parciais. É uma lógica bastante simples porque grande parte das folhas de estilo escritas em SASS é formada de vários arquivos parciais e uma versão "compilada" deles.

O font-awesome, por exemplo, usa dessa estrura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde só o arquivo font-awesome.scss é compilado em CSS e os outros são parciais que o compõe.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Como o `SASS` interpreta arquivos com `'_'` como parciais, basta você renomear o arquivo para um nome "comum" que tudo será compilado de acordo.

Mas atenção: geralmente `Frameworks` e bibliotecas fazem uso de parciais justamente para que estes arquivos *não sejam compilados*.

A maneira correta de usar parciais é importá-los no arquivo `SASS` que será compilado. O compilador vai escrever no `CSS` somente as classes/funções que realmente foram usadas desse parcial, e não o arquivo inteiro.